# Rails 5: Gem bcrypt - is throwing an error "cannot load such file -- bcrypt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt-ruby

I am a Rails beginner. When i am trying to use gem bcrypt, i see an error on my screen "cannot load such file -- bcrypt" control stuck at 'has_secure_password' line of Model.

**Server logs**

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt):

app/models/user.rb:3:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `new'
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-18 15:03:08 +0530
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt):

app/models/user.rb:3:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

**Gem file**

```
#gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

I've used both the above gems executing one at time. Even after checking out many blogs and sites, i could not find a solution.

I could bring up my rails server with no issues, but could not open my View in the browser.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows then follow the steps

Run this for uninstalling

```
gem uninstall bcrypt
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
```

Then install using

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

if you using `devise` then not need to add `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'` to you Gemfile because it included `devise` gem

Otherwise, add this gem to your gem file not need to run bundle installing or update

After all of this don't forget to restart your server.

Hope it helps